# Some workstations/servers on the domain respond with IPv6 instead of IPv4 addresses, even though IPv6 is disabled across the board

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, ipv6

Earlier this week I've noticed some issues on my network. For example when I ping my machine (from my machine) using the hostname (or FQDN), I see a response from an IPv6 address.

C:\Windows\system32>ping nyl000 
Pinging NYL000.domain.com [fe80::65fd:46bd:c2a3:435%35] with 32 bytes of data: 
Reply from fe80::65fd:46bd:c2a3:435%35: time<1ms 
Reply from fe80::65fd:46bd:c2a3:435%35: time<1ms 
Reply from fe80::65fd:46bd:c2a3:435%35: time<1ms 
Reply from fe80::65fd:46bd:c2a3:435%35: time<1ms

IPv6 is disabled on my workstation.

When I ping my machine from a different workstation I get an IPv4 address as a response.

C:\Documents and Settings\administrator.MECHONET>ping nyl000

Pinging nyl000.domain.com [10.1.100.95] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 10.1.100.95: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=125
Reply from 10.1.100.95: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=125
Reply from 10.1.100.95: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=125
Reply from 10.1.100.95: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=125

I have two DCs (2003 and 2008 R2) acting as DNS servers for this domain and IPv6 is disabled on both.

Strangely enough, in dnsmgmt on my DC i see 7 AAAA records for servers on my domain. All of these servers have the TCP/IPv6 checkbox unchecked under the NIC properties.

In addition, when I do nslookup on my workstation I get this:

C:\Windows\system32>nslookup server
Server:  dns.domain.com
Address:  192.168.4.4

Name:    server.domain.com
Addresses:  2002:c001:205::c001:205
          192.168.2.5

When i do the same thing from the DC, I get this:
C:>nslookup server
Server:  dns.domain.com
Address:  192.168.4.4

Name:    server.domain.com
Address:  192.168.2.5

Any thoughts on where this IPv6 is coming from?

Cheers,

Marvin

Comment: Caching? Try a `ipconfig /flushdns` on your workstation and then try again. Also manually yank out the AAAA records in your DNS to make sure.

Comment: Take a look at Microsoft's recommendation about [disabling IPv6](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/cc987595.aspx#EDC): "From Microsoft's perspective, IPv6 is a mandatory part of the Windows operating system"

Comment: "IPv6 is disabled on my workstation": Seeing as actual IPv6 packets are getting sent and responded to, that's clearly not true :-)

Comment: Nathan C:I have tried ipconfig/flushdns but it didn't do anything.
Celada: Agreed, except this issue started happening this week (wasn't happening before), and as I said all of the NICs on the network have IPv6 unchecked. In addition, I've followed Microsoft guidelines outlined here -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/cc987595.aspx (as r.tanner.f mentioned) on how to disable it, but the issue persists.
I am truly at a loss as to why it is happening...